# JavaScript function to show GIF

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I am just starting out with HTML5. I have written lots of programs in C but now I wanted to learn HTML5. I am trying to write a game about Zombies and I need to display a GIF, but my function `showGif` is not working and I can't figure out why. Can you help me?

I first show the background image and then I am trying to show the GIF on top of the background inside the canvas.

I don't know how to attach here the image files but the sources in the code are correct I double checked.

Probably there more errors than just in the function and I would appreciate that you point them out so I can learn.

```js
window.onload = function()
{
    var c=document.getElementById("gameCanvas");

    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

    var background = new Image();

    background.src = "imgs/background.png";

    background.onload = function()
    {
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
    };

    var imgSrc = ["imgs/zombieGif/frame0.png", "imgs/zombieGif/frame1.png", "imgs/zombieGif/frame2.png", "imgs/zombieGif/frame3.png", "imgs/zombieGif/frame4.png", "imgs/zombieGif/frame5.png", "imgs/zombieGif/frame6.png", "imgs/zombieGif/frame7.png"];

    showGif(imgSrc, 8);

    function showGif(imgSrc, num)
    {

        for(var i=0; i<num; i++)
        {
            var curImg = new Image();

            curImg.src = imgSrc[i];

            curImg.style.zIndex = "1";

            curImg.onload = function()
            {
                ctx.drawImage(curImg, 0, 0);
            };
        }
    }
};
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Architects Daughter', cursive;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Zombies</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Architects+Daughter" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Zombies</h1>
  <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="1140" height="540"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advence for your time.

Ps: Sorry for occasional mistakes on my English.

Comment: You are confusing canvas with an image. You cannot change image zIndex after drawing it on a canvas... Btw, that's not the problem.

Comment: Are there any error messages in your console? Can you check and share them if any?

Comment: your `img` tag probably hasn't loaded the image yet. Try using the [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) event

Comment: No, the console doens't show any errors.

Comment: You seem to have a grasp of how animation frames work, but not so much how the canvas works. You might want to consider a game framework like Phaser.io that handles synchronous loading and animating of sprites, refreshing the game canvas, asset management, tweens, collision, etc. I tried rolling my own but gave up and switched to a framework. (I am not affiliated with Phaser.io.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing a blank image, as when you set the source of the image, the browser has to make an HTTP request and load the data inside the image element. Meanwhile the javascript code is running (this is called asynchronous load), so when you reach the `ctx.drawImage` method, the browser is still making the HTTP request to load the image.

A canvas is not al element which updates with your image updates. A canvas is just a set of pixels where you draw your elements. Is just that, a pixel canvas, like a painting canvas.

You need to load the images, **wait for them to be loaded** and draw all the image pixels inside the canvas **after the image element has all the image data loaded**. You can attach an event handler to the `load` event.

For this you need to learn about callbacks and such, so if you don't know what I'm talking about, do not try to build the house from the roof. Get a "javascript for begginers" tutorial and read it from the bottom. Specially search something talking about *asynchronous callbacks*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer. I will read about asynchronous callbacks, and then rewrite my function.

Comment: I have read about asynchronous callbacks, and applied to my code however it still doens't  show the gif or at least the first frame. I put everything inside window.onload= function(){} and I also changed the images so now they are png instead of gif.

Comment: @Roman As I've stated, you cannot expect to the gif be redrawn on each frame inside the canvas. You will just get the first frame and draw it on the canvas. On each `drawImage` call, you will move what you see in the image and copy those pixels to the canvas. Also, please update the question with what have you tried about the async callbacks so we can further help you.

Comment: @Roman The onload will throw the first time when the window is loaded. You must listen to the load event **of each image** to know that each image has been loaded. Each image will have its own pace when loading, as browsers usually uses independent connections for each request.

Comment: @Roman Listening for the window onload for the images being loaded is like listening for the smartphone when your door beel is ringing. Completely different things. If you want to know when the door is ringing (aka, the image is loaded), you must listen for the door (aka, the image).

Comment: After looking at the debugger I think I now what is happening. Like you said the browser is loading the images at the same time but the backgroung image is bigger and is taking longer to load than the curImage, so the curImg is drawn and after that the background is drawn over the last image. That's is why sometimes I can see the curImage and sometimes I can't.

Comment: I did it. I placed a callback() inside background.onload(function()) that calls the showGif(). Thank you for your help.